# Is there anything like "CheckSum" in Dart (on Objects)?

Tags: dart, checksum

For Testing purposes I'm trying to design a way to verify that the results of statistical tests are identical across versions, platforms and such.  There are a lot things that go on that include ints, nums, dates, Strings and more inside our collections of Objects.

In the end I want to 'know' that the whole set of instantiated objects sum to the same value (by just doing something like adding the checkSum of all internal properties).

I can write low level code for each internal value to return a checkSum but I was thinking that perhaps something like this already exists.

Thanks!

_swarmii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you should be using the [`serialization`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/serialization.html) library ([install via Pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/serialization)).

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:serialization/serialization.dart';

class Address {
  String street;
  int number;
}

main() {
  var address = new Address()
    ..number = 5
    ..street = 'Luumut';

  var serialization = new Serialization()
    ..addRuleFor(address);

  Map output = serialization.write(address, new SimpleJsonFormat());

  print(output);
}
```

Then depending on what you want to do exactly, I'm sure you can fine tune the code for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you Herra Sellgren,  This would seem to be the best way to get to an unique string.  Now to get from a string to Hash value of some sort - but even if I do that myself it should not be difficult...  Thanks again!  Swarmii

Comment: Did you intentionally write Finnish? :P

Comment: Kiitos Taas, Joo I didn't. :)

Comment: JSON is spitting up on me, looks like some unsupported Object type.  I'm using int and it is not explicitly mentioned as such as supported and its not telling me how its failing.  I don't have time/energy to research this now but will post something on the Dart forum.  Can't believe I'd be forced to use 'num' type over 'int' but I expect to need JSON for communications to Server at this same level so this is a project level issue for me long term also.  In meantime I'm just going to do my own "stringify" on the internal objects and try to figure out what's going on (if its a bug).

Comment: FYI:  I haven't seen it documented just yet, but there is a 'stringify' property available in the objects I was looking at.  Probably in all objects?  IF I could have used this with the checkSum it would have been a very simple and probably relatively high performance solution.  However, the CheckSum returned on this property was varying, and I have no clue why. My solution has been to stringify using Dart's built in string handling and the string.concat(otherString) command for all the values of interest to me, and this works nicely and consistently as I would expect it to.